# Initialize a Stripe Object in new Android Studio

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, android-context

Currently, I am working to create a Stripe payment method in an Android Studio App. This will involve a credit card object which will be stored by Stripe into my Firestore DB. Unfortunately, one of the lines in the tutorial that I have used is outdated since it uses getContext() without a view.

Background on Stripe:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE

Background on Firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Here is the link to the tutorial that I am following:
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android
Unfortunately, I have not had much luck finding a tutorial that is knew, uses the same format and does not use getContext().

I have already completed all steps up to inserting the line:

```
final Stripe stripe = new Stripe(
    getContext(),
    "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx"
);
```

In my version of Android Studio (3.4.1), it seems getContext() cannot be used without a View (shows up as red). As a result, I have tried to substitute a variety of commands. However, they all produce the same crash with message "Invalid Content Provider: null". I believe that "Content Provider" refers to the Context passed in.

I should mention that the Stripe object is created within an On-Click listener. Further, I know that the "pk_test" key is correct and I have tested other valid ids also to no avail. Further, through tests with commenting out code, I am certain that this is the line producing my error.

My theory is that the context is being rejected by Stripe or Firebase. This is because the Stripe Context is known as a "Stripe Provider" (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ByYW3X0ua38/XQ_kRpmddLI/AAAAAAAAAAI/YfhjxSJ9iO0aJwZ8RtANeCXKXyYglWX1QCK8BGAs/s0/2019-06-23.png)

Some of the commands that I have tried are:

```
getContext() (not recognized)
getApplicationContext()
getBaseContext()
this
this.getApplicationContext()
ClassName.this.getApplicationContext()
ClassName.this.getBaseContext()
Submit.getContext()
WrappingLayoutView.getContext()
```

I have also tried to capture the Context in OnCreate above the OnClick listener in a variable.

Since none of these are working, I am rather stuck as to what to do. 
Here is my Java Code:

public class AddCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button submit;

```
public Context mContext;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_card);
    init();

    mContext = this.getApplicationContext();

    //Not working
    /**View mV=findViewById(R.id.myLView);
     mContext=mV.getContext();**/
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             //Use stripe to add new payment to firestore


            //This line causes a crash
            Stripe stripe = new Stripe(submit.getContext(),
                    "pk_test_t6NMvJpXDEZd3eOn5SU4y6DA"
            );
            // The Card class will normalize the card number
            final Card card = Card.create("4242-4242-4242-4242", 12, 2020, "123");
            //Update this with more useful error messages
            if (card == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Card!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            card.validateNumber();
            card.validateCVC();
            stripe.createToken(
                    card,
                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Token token) {
                            // Send token to your server
                        }

                        public void onError(@NonNull Exception error) {
                            // Show localized error message
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Card!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });


}

private void init() {
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCardActivityButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Token token = null;

final Card card = new Card(cardNumber, month, year, cvc);

final Stripe stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext());
try {

    token = stripe.createTokenSynchronous(card, "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx");

} catch (StripeException stripeEx) {

    errorMessage = stripeEx.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```